# Windows 7 flickers then freezes

Tags: windows-7

This past week, once in a while, my screen will flicker then after a few moments in will freeze and I have to reboot it. Any ideas what could be causing this? I am using built-in video card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video scrambling then crashing is likely to be something related to the graphics chip or memory (since you have onboard graphics it will share the memory).

Start by updating your graphics driver. Even if the problem is not driver related, a new version may bring features that make it more resilient to hardware failure.

If the problem persist, clean the connections of your memory modules. If you don't have a contact cleaner, a soft rubber should get the job done.

If it persist and you have more than one memory module, remove one of them and see if the problem persist while using only the other. Cycle them in case it crash again to test both modules.

If nothing helped and the problem remain unidentified, you probably need a graphics card.

Comment: It might be useful to note that flickering and video based freezes could be caused by excessive heat.